# Smart search results override not working joomla 3.2

Tags: php, search, joomla, joomla3.2

I am trying to change some things on the smart search results page using overrides. It seems to me that my overrides are not working as I don't see *any* change when I change the code.

I tried various things, just taking out the relevant code, removing the whole code of the override as well as just removing random bits of code that should surely create some errors.

The file I am trying to override is the default_results.php file.

What I am trying to do (I don't know if this is relevant, I'll just post it anyway):

- remove the 'examples of how you can use the search feature' text
- remove the 'search by author', 'search by category' and 'search by type' text and dropdown menu
- and the link that appears below every search result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like didn't set the override correctly. The `default_results.php` should be located in

```
\templates\YOURTEMPLATE\html\com_finder\search\default_results.php
```

And make sure you did it for the right domain, since that's what happened to me today, wondering why override wasn't working, while all the time I was editing the file under a wrong domain...

Comment: the override was in the right folder, however, I did not realize I had to make an override of com_finder. I made an override of com_search initially. In the com_finder override there are two files, default_result.php and default_result **s** .php, what's the difference?

Comment: Also, what do I need to change to get the desired results? I don't really understand the code very well. I imagine to take out the 'examples on how to use the search...' I need to remove lines 40-44, when I do this though, nothing happens...

Comment: The `default_result.php` renders a single result. For example, if the search returned 10 results, that file will be included 10 times to show the result. Everything above and bellow results comes from file `default_results.php`. But for some of those options, you can also go to Components -> Smart Search, click on options, and disable what you don't need